# What is the valid isoformat string for creating calendar events with google api

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I deployed the fast api application meant to recieve post request from a script I wrote, my application in fast api is logging: An error occurred while creating the event: Invalid isoformat string: '2023-08-27T05:13:00Z'

this is my fast api

```
import uvicorn
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

# Set up Google Calendar credentials
def get_calendar_service():
    credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        "path/to/my/service.json",
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    )
    return build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

class EventData(BaseModel):
    email: str
    name: str
    event_name: str
    event_address: str
    event_date: str

# Function to generate a unique event ID
def generate_event_id():
    return str(datetime.now().timestamp()).replace('.', '')

# Function to create an event in Google Calendar
def create_google_calendar_event(service, event_name, event_date, event_address, name, email):
    try:
        # Check if the event date is in the correct format
        try:
            datetime.strptime(event_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        except ValueError:
            print(f'Invalid event date format: {event_date}. The event date must be in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ.')
            return None

        event = {
            'summary': event_name,
            'location': event_address,
            'description': f'An event created for {name} ({email})',
            'start': {
                'dateTime': event_date,
                'timeZone': 'UTC',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': (datetime.fromisoformat(event_date) + timedelta(hours=1)).isoformat(),
                'timeZone': 'UTC',
            },
            'attendees': [
                {'email': email},
            ],
            'reminders': {
                'useDefault': True,
            },
        }
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
        return event.get('htmlLink')
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'An error occurred while creating the event: {error}')
        return None

def send_email(to_email, subject, body):
    from_email = 'email@gmail.com'
    password = 'password'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(from_email, password)
    server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

@app.post('/invite')
async def invite(data: EventData):
    try:
        # Use the input data from the request
        email = data.email
        name = data.name
        event_name = data.event_name
        event_address = data.event_address
        event_date = data.event_date

        # Generate unique event ID
        event_id = generate_event_id()

        # Create Google Calendar event and get sharable link
        service = get_calendar_service()
        event_link = create_google_calendar_event(service, event_name, event_date, event_address, name, email)

        # Send email invitation to user with sharable link to calendar event
        subject = f'Invitation: {event_name}'
        body = f'Dear {name},\n\nYou are invited to attend the following event:\n\nName: {event_name}\nDate: {event_date}\nAddress: {event_address}\n\nPlease click on the following link to view the calendar and confirm your attendance:\n\n{event_link}\n\nBest regards,\nThe Event Team'
        send_email(email, subject, body)

        return {'message': 'Invitation sent successfully'}
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred in the invite function: {e}')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Internal Server Error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

this is the script i use to collect input and send a post request

```
import requests

# Replace with the URL of your deployed FastAPI app
api_url = "https://my/deployed/fast/api/app.com/invite"

# User input
email = input("Enter your email: ")
name = input("Enter your name: ")
event_name = input("Enter event name: ")
event_address = input("Enter event address: ")

# User input for event date
event_date_input = input("Enter event date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
event_time_input = input("Enter event time (HH:MM): ")

try:
    # Separate date and time inputs and format them correctly
    event_date = event_date_input
    event_time = event_time_input + ":00Z"  # Adding seconds and 'Z' for UTC timezone

    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "email": email,
        "name": name,
        "event_name": event_name,
        "event_address": event_address,
        "event_date": f"{event_date}T{event_time}",
    }

    # Send POST request
    response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload)

    # Check response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Invitation sent successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to send invitation.")
        print("Response:", response.text)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid date or time format. Please use YYYY-MM-DD for date and HH:MM for time.")
    exit()
```

I tried altering the date format because i do believe the main issue is in the date format, the email does send but the event isn't created and the link returns none as it should.

for example this is an error log i get: An error occurred while creating the event: Invalid isoformat string: '2023-08-27T05:13:00Z'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the 'Z' at the end of the string, which represents the UTC timezone. The `fromisoformat` method does not support the 'Z' suffix.

To fix this, you can remove the 'Z' from the string before passing it to `fromisoformat`.

Here's how you might modify the relevant part of your FastAPI code:

Change this line:

```py
'dateTime': (datetime.fromisoformat(event_date) + timedelta(hours=1)).isoformat(),
```

To:

```py
'dateTime': (datetime.fromisoformat(event_date.replace("Z", "")) + timedelta(hours=1)).isoformat() + "Z",
```

This will remove the 'Z' before converting the string to a datetime object and then add it back when converting the datetime object to a string.